# How can I delete related child entities from DB when I set parent entity's value to null using Entity Framework and CodeFirst approach?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, cascading-deletes

For Example I have `Order` and this order has `Reserve` field which has `ICollection<ReserveItem>`.
What I have now is:

**Order class**

```
public class Order
{
    ...
    public Reserve Reserve {get; private set;}

    public void ClearReserve()
    {
        // Reserve.Items = null; or Resrver.Items.Clear()
        Reserve = null;
    }
}
```

**Reserve class**

```
public class Reserve
{
     public ICollection<ReserveItems> Items {get; set;}
     public DateTime ExpireDate {get; set;}
}
```

and **OrderRepository class**

```
public OrderRepository
{
   ...
   public void ClearOrderReserve(Order order)   
   {
       order.ClearReserve();
       repostiry.InsertOrUpdate(order);
   }
   ...
}
```

in my **database context class** I have:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Reserve>()
                .HasMany(pr => pr.Items)
                .WithRequired()
                .WillCascadeOnDelete();
    ...
}
```

How can I correctly delete `Order.Reserve` field (set it's value to `null`) in `OrderRepository.ClearOrderReserve(Order order)` method and initiate cascade on delete to remove redundant `ICollection<ReserveItem>` records from database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting reserve to null will not delete it. You must delete it through `DbSet<Reserve>`'s `Remove` method.